# Why is the Identifier not valid? The column is in the corr synt. on the sour datab with the corr nam, Power Query Editor tool, Extended Editor tool

Tags: powerbi, editor, powerquery, odb

```
// Join data and fill in the monthly columns
    JoinedTable = Table.Join(ChangedTypes, {"CustomerNo"}, FilteredRows, {"Customer No_"}),
    FilledColumns = Table.TransformColumns(JoinedTable, {
        {"January", each if [Month] = 1 then [ImportedSales(LCY)] else null, type number},
        {"February", each if [Month] = 2 then [ImportedSales(LCY)] else null, type number},
        {"March", each if [Month] = 3 then [ImportedSales(LCY)] else null, type number},
```

He renamed the column, removed the source table, installed it again, updated it. He renamed it again. Checked everything OK on the connection.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
let JoinedTable = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(JoinedTable, "Custom", each Date.MonthName(#date(2000,[Month],1))),
#"Duplicated Column" = Table.DuplicateColumn(#"Added Custom", "ImportedSales(LCY)", "copy"),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Duplicated Column", List.Distinct(#"Duplicated Column"[Custom]), "Custom", "copy")
in  #"Pivoted Column"
```

[image]

Among the issues with your original is that you need to refer to your column as [#"ImportedSales(LCY)"] and that it is a terrible way to do it